# Different conditionals on the same Dockerfile

Tags: docker, shell, dockerfile, docker-multi-stage-build

I have a Dockerfile with some commands I would like to use conditionally:

1. `FROM + image_name` (I have a M1 chip MacOS so I need to add `--platform=linux/amd64` to it but I want to deploy in a AWS EC2 linux instance that doesn't need it)
2. On production I would like to run my project with nginx so I want the Dockerfile to end with this `RUN mkdir -p tmp/sockets`. But for testing, I have no need of the nginx so I would like my Dockerfile to end with this

```
# Expose port 
EXPOSE 3000

# Start rails
CMD ["rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

I thought of using the `multi stage dockerfile` to solve the `FROM image` problem but the Dockerfile resulting is quite lengthy since it is basically the same except for the `FROM image` part.
For the `nginx` part I wanted to use a shell script but I am not sure how to write the exposing port and final command to start rails.
These are the files:

`run_dockerfile.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ ${RUN_DOCKERFILE} = "PROD" ]; then 
    mkdir -p tmp/sockets
else
    ????
fi
```

My `Dockerfile`looks like this:

```
# Start from the official ruby image
# To run Dockerfile with arm64 architecture (M1 chip MacOS for example)
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 ruby:2.6.6 AS ARM64

# Set environment
ARG BUILD_DEVELOPMENT
# if --build-arg BUILD_DEVELOPMENT=1, set RAILS_ENV to 'development' or set to null otherwise.
ENV RAILS_ENV=${BUILD_DEVELOPMENT:+development}
# if RAILS_ENV is null, set it to 'production' (or leave as is otherwise).
ENV RAILS_ENV=${RAILS_ENV:-production}

# Update and install JS & DB
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y nodejs postgresql-client

# Create a directory for the application and use it
RUN mkdir /myapp
WORKDIR /myapp

# Gemfile and lock file need to be present, they'll be overwritten immediately
COPY Gemfile /myapp/Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock /myapp/Gemfile.lock

# Install gem dependencies
RUN gem install bundler:2.2.32
RUN bundle install
RUN curl https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | bash
ADD https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg /tmp/yarn-pubkey.gpg
RUN apt-key add /tmp/yarn-pubkey.gpg && rm /tmp/yarn-pubkey.gpg
RUN echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y yarn  && apt-get install -y npm
RUN yarn add bootstrap

COPY . /myapp

# So that webpacker compiles
RUN yarn config set ignore-engines true
RUN rm -rf bin/webpack*
RUN rails webpacker:install
RUN bundle exec rails webpacker:compile
RUN bundle exec rake assets:precompile

# This script runs every time the container is created, necessary for rails
COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint.sh"]


# Run run_dockerfile.sh
COPY run_dockerfile.sh run_dockerfile.sh
RUN chmod u+x run_dockerfile.sh && ./run_dockerfile.sh


##################################################

# Start from the official ruby image
# To run Dockerfile without arm64 architecture
FROM ruby:2.6.6 AS AMD64

# Set environment
ARG BUILD_DEVELOPMENT
# if --build-arg BUILD_DEVELOPMENT=1, set RAILS_ENV to 'development' or set to null otherwise.
ENV RAILS_ENV=${BUILD_DEVELOPMENT:+development}
# if RAILS_ENV is null, set it to 'production' (or leave as is otherwise).
ENV RAILS_ENV=${RAILS_ENV:-production}

# Update and install JS & DB
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y nodejs postgresql-client

# Create a directory for the application and use it
RUN mkdir /myapp
WORKDIR /myapp

# Gemfile and lock file need to be present, they'll be overwritten immediately
COPY Gemfile /myapp/Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock /myapp/Gemfile.lock

# Install gem dependencies
RUN gem install bundler:2.2.32
RUN bundle install
RUN curl https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | bash
ADD https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg /tmp/yarn-pubkey.gpg
RUN apt-key add /tmp/yarn-pubkey.gpg && rm /tmp/yarn-pubkey.gpg
RUN echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y yarn  && apt-get install -y npm
RUN yarn add bootstrap

COPY . /myapp

# So that webpacker compiles
RUN yarn config set ignore-engines true
RUN rm -rf bin/webpack*
RUN rails webpacker:install
RUN bundle exec rails webpacker:compile
RUN bundle exec rake assets:precompile

# This script runs every time the container is created, necessary for rails
COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint.sh"]

# Run run_dockerfile.sh
COPY run_dockerfile.sh run_dockerfile.sh
RUN chmod u+x run_dockerfile.sh && ./run_dockerfile.sh
```

Is there any way I could do the `.sh` or are there any recommendations on the proper way to do it? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the way you've described the problem, you don't really need very many special cases at all.

The one important detail is that it's very easy to override the image's `CMD` when you run a container.  If you have [two Compose files](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/), for example, you can just set the service's `command:`

```yaml
# docker-compose.yml
version: '3.8'
services:
  myapp:
    image: registry.example.com/myapp:${MYAPP_TAG:-latest}
    ports: ['3000:80']
```

```yaml
# docker-compose.override.yml
# for developer use
version: '3.8'
services:
  myapp:
    build: .
    command: rails server -b 0.0.0.0 -p 80
```

The other variations you list shouldn't matter.  You should get consistent results if you build your image `FROM --platform=linux/amd64` on an x86-64 host, explicitly specifying the native platform; `RUN mkdir` a directory you won't use is harmless.  The one inconsistency seems to be the container port, but you can explicitly tell `rails server` which port to use so it matches.  I'd use the same image in all environments.

```sh
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 ruby:2.6.6 # even on an Intel/AMD host system
...
RUN mkdir tmp/sockets                  # even if it's unused
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]     # can be overridden when the container runs
```